# Accessing Javascript variable in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, fullscreen, jsni

I have a variable in Javascript, which toggles between `true` and `false` when full-screen mode is switched on and off, respectively. Now I want to access that variable in my `GWT` code, and do some actions accordingly. Can anyone tell me how to do it? I couldn't understand it from the Google documentation on `JSNI`...

Comment: The selected answer doesnt work !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In JavaScript**

```
var mybool = true;
```

**your [JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) method in MyClass class ;**

```
public static native boolean getNativeVariableType(String jsVar)/*-{
        return  eval('$wnd.' + jsVar);
    }-*/;
```

**Finally using in  GWT ;**

```
boolean getFormJs = Myclass.getNativeVariableType("mybool");
```

As @dodoot raised the point you can try this `return !!$wnd[jsVar]` to get ridoff `eval` function side effects.

As @manolo said  if you are using [gwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) it will be more handy by writing simply `$(window).prop("mybool")`.

Comment: -1, eval is always a security issue in javascript (as well as in other scripting languages). Its better (and shorter) just to test if the var exists, change all the jsni block by `return !!$wnd[jsVar]`

Comment: @Dodoot .Agreed .as long as you are on client side the eval wont be cause any damage..if you hit the server and then using eval will cause injections.Of course its better to take this point into consider .Cheers :)

Comment: @Baadshah your second solution doesnt work at all!!, It always look for the property 'jsVar' in window instead of replacing with the value passed as parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a curiosity, for simple things like this, you can avoid writing jsni methods by taking advantage of certain jsni methods already present in gwt overlay classes.

So in your case you can get the window object, and casting it to an element, read its properties with getters from the `Element` class :

```
Element $wnd = (Element)Document.get().<Element>cast().getPropertyObject("defaultView");
boolean mybool = $wnd.getPropertyBoolean("mybool");
```

Adding the gwtquery library to your project, the code is much simpler:

```
boolean mybool = $(window).prop("mybool");
```

Comment: Impressive!, @Manolo is there a way to do it with gwtquery?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **do it with GWTQuery**?

Comment: well, gwtquery aka gquery is an amazing library to manipulate dom and js objects from java, and @Manolo is the guy behind it :-)

Comment: @Manolo GwtQuery makes it simple, and I believe you are the project lead for that right?